# Selecionar Arquivo PDF da minha galeria

Tags: android

Boa Tarde estou tentando selecionar um arquivo pdf da minha galeria porém ele me retorna a seguinte mensagem : "Impossivel localizar aplicação para executar esta ação")

Versão Android 4.1.2

Estou utilizando o seguinte código :

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(
                Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select txt file"),
                0);
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        // Potentially direct the user to the Market with a Dialog

    }
}
```

Comment: O dispositivo tem alguma aplicação que possa abrir PDF's?

Comment: Tem sim! em o Adobe!